# Nested namespace definition when the enclosing namespace is inline

Tags: c++, namespaces, definition, c++20, inline-namespaces

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

inline namespace A
{
}

namespace A:: inline B
{
    void f() { std::cout << "Hello nested namespace definition.\n"; }
}

int main() 
{
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

The result of the compilation of the program by the compiler `clang HEAD 11.0.0` is the following

```
prog.cc:7:11: warning: inline namespace reopened as a non-inline namespace
namespace A:: inline B
          ^
inline 
prog.cc:3:18: note: previous definition is here
inline namespace A
                 ^
1 warning generated.
Hello nested namespace definition.
```

But according to the grammar of the nested namespace definition I may not use the keyword `inline` before the namespace A.

So is it a bug of the compiler or am I doing something wrong?

By the way the compiler `gcc HEAD 10.0.1 20200` compiles the program without any warning.

Comment: I really don't understand why you DV my answer, the probem was not the dereferencing part, that was actually correct, initially I thought so aswell, the problem was the for loops limits were the other way around. I actually apreciate your answers and  UV them many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixit-hint for clang is misleading (since you cannot actually do the thing it is telling you to do), but the program is fine (although misleading, since it looks like you're declaring a non-inline namespace when you're really not - so the warning isn't entirely unreasonable).

---

Ignoring nested namespaces for the moment, this is actually fine:

```
inline namespace N { int i=0; };
namespace N { int j=1; };
int k=j;
```

The only rule we have, from [[namespace.def]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.namespace#namespace.def-5.sentence-2), is (emphasis mine):

> The `inline` keyword may be used on a *namespace-definition* that extends a namespace **only if** it was previously used on the *namespace-definition* that initially declared the *namespace-name* for that namespace.

The wording is "only if", not "if and only if" - so you can't mark a namespace `inline` that was previously not marked... but if the first declaration of a namespace is `inline`, not every subsequent declaration has to be.

As noted in OP, clang warns on this anyway. Because it's kind of misleading.

---

But why can't we just stick a leading `inline` in there?

As described in [the paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1094r2.html), the problem with allowing nested namespace with the *leading* namespace `inline` is that it leads to ambiguity for programmers:

```
inline namespace std::experimental::parallelism_v2;  // not immediately to reader,
                                                     // is std or parallelism_v2 inline?
```

And the same would be true if you harmonized the leading `inline` with the nested `inline` by putting it on the other side of `namespace`:

```
namespace inline std::experimental::parallelism_v2;  // immediately to reader?
                                                     // std or parallelism_v2 inline?
```

So it's imply not supported. If you want a nested namespace with the top-level namespace `inline`... you can't. The top-level namespace must be non-`inline` (I suppose we could've considered syntax like `namespace ::inline N::inline M` but that's just weird in its own way).

---

Comment: But in the C++ 20 Standard there is nothing said that this definition is ill-formed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Reordered the answer so it's more clear that I'm not saying the definition is ill-formed.